# Python prints both "if" scenarios even though 1 clearly does not apply

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is my code:

```
varsec =raw_input("enter secret number between 1 and 100(the system won't know):")

if int(varsec.strip()) >=100: print("Cheater caught! >:D")

if int(varsec.strip()) <=1: print("Cheater caught! >:D")

import random

varGuess = random.randint(2,99)

if 2 <= int(varsec.strip()) <= 99 : print(varGuess,
                                          ("If this number is less than your secret number, type <, if more then type >, if it IS your secret number then type =."))


VarConfirm = raw_input(":")


if (VarConfirm.strip()) is "<": from random import randint
print(randint(varGuess + 1,99))

if (VarConfirm.strip()) is ">": from random import randint
print(randint(2,varGuess - 1))

if (VarConfirm.strip()) is "=": print("YES, the program has successfully guessed your number ^^")
```

If I type "<" for `VarConfirm`, it prints both numbers (1 number that is between `varGuess +1` and `99` inclusive and the other is `2` and `varGuess -1` inclusive).

I want it to only print the number that is between `varGuess + 1` and `99` inclusive.

Also, when I type `"<"` or `"="` it comes up with `NameError: 'randint' is not defined.`

Comment: Is this the real indentation you're using in the code?

Comment: Although you *can* conditionally import things, and it will work as you might expect, I'm not sure it's necessary in this case.  At least it's not obvious from the code you posted.  And in the (very likely) case that it's unnecessary, it will just serve to clutter and confuse.

Comment: @Sayse: it must be, because all reported errors flow from that indentation.

Comment: By the way, your `NameError` comes up when you type `>` or `=`, not `<`.

Answer (score 4):

You did not indent your `print` statements. They are executed **always**, regardless of the `if` tests.

Python forms blocks by indentation; you need to put all lines that can only be executed when an `if` test is true, at the same indentation, and that indentation needs to be greater than the `if` line itself:

```
if (VarConfirm.strip()) is "<":
    from random import randint
    print(randint(varGuess + 1,99))

if (VarConfirm.strip()) is ">":
    from random import randint
    print(randint(2,varGuess - 1))
```

Note that I put the `import` statements on a *new line* here. You can put the 'block' on the same line as the `if` statement, but than that block is limited to just *one simple statement*; you can't do more than one thing.

You also should not be using `is` to test for string equality; these tests should normally fail because the `raw_input()` function is not required to return the *exact same object in memory* you used to test with. That CPython does anyway is an internal implementation detail that you can't rely on. You want to test if their *value* is equal:

```
if (VarConfirm.strip()) == "<":
    from random import randint
    print(randint(varGuess + 1,99))

if (VarConfirm.strip()) == ">":
    from random import randint
    print(randint(2,varGuess - 1))
```

However, your imports add new globals to your file; just leave them *at the top* of your script:

```
from random import randint

# other code

if (VarConfirm.strip()) == "<":
    print(randint(varGuess + 1,99))

if (VarConfirm.strip()) == ">":
    print(randint(2,varGuess - 1))
```

or just use `random.randint()`; you already imported the `random` module earlier:

```
if (VarConfirm.strip()) == "<":
    print(random.randint(varGuess + 1,99))

if (VarConfirm.strip()) == ">":
    print(random.randint(2,varGuess - 1))
```

You don't need to use so many parentheses; in Python 2 `print` is a statement, not a function (just like `return`):

```
if VarConfirm.strip() == "<":
    print random.randint(varGuess + 1,99)

if VarConfirm.strip() == ">":
    print random.randint(2,varGuess - 1)
```

Because your tests are mutually exclusive, you can use `if ... elif ...` and Python will only have to keep testing until *one* of the tests is true:

```
if VarConfirm.strip() == "<":
    print random.randint(varGuess + 1,99)

elif VarConfirm.strip() == ">":
    print random.randint(2,varGuess - 1)

elif VarConfirm.strip() == "=":
    print "YES, the program has successfully guessed your number ^^"
```

You could avoid calling `.strip()` so often; just call it once and store the result:

```
# ask for the input and strip immediately before storing the result:
VarConfirm = raw_input(":").strip()

if VarConfirm == "<":
    print random.randint(varGuess + 1,99)

elif VarConfirm == ">":
    print random.randint(2,varGuess - 1)

elif VarConfirm == "=":
    print "YES, the program has successfully guessed your number ^^"
```

Comment: Nice "improvement by dissection" approach. +1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you copying the code here messed up your indentation, but your indentation suggests that the part after the ":" in your if statements counts as the **only** conditional part, and then the print statements are just normal python lines, completely independent from the if statement.

Also, there's no need to import something like that in the middle of an if statement. Just make the import statement in the beginning of your program and use it from then on. So your code should be

```
from random import randint

# [.... previous steps ....]

if (VarConfirm.strip()) == "<":
    print randint(varGuess + 1,99)

if (VarConfirm.strip()) == ">":
    print randint(2,varGuess-1)

if (VarConfirm.strip()) == "=":
    print "Yes, bla bla"
```

Comment: The indentation they used explains the import error; the first `if` doesn't match, so the `import` doesn't run, and the `print` is run instead with `randint` not imported.

Comment: also, I suspect the `NameError: 'randint' is not defined` error came up with ">" and "=", and not with "<" and "=" as you stated in your question (unless you switched the order from your original code you tested). This would make sense, because if the first if statement fails, then the print line which is (accidentally) a normal line, will run and fail to find a definition for "randint", since it never got imported.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it doesn't with "<", unless he got confused and meant ">"  :p

Comment: It does with all three because `is "<"` is never true.

Comment: oh you're right ... duh. I corrected it on my snippet and forgot that was the case. nice.

Comment: Ah, except it turns out `raw_input()` sometimes interns strings too. So it *can* be true and that's a CPython implementation detail.